# How to check if message for window.addEventListener("message") is from a specific iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension where I have a content script which injects an iframe into the page, I can send a message specifically from the content script to the iframe with iframeVariable.postMessage but I can't specifically send message to the content script as the parent.window.postMessage posts message entirely onto the page to which any script can listen to, I tried with the e.target == iframeVariable but it doesn't work. So for the moment for security concerns I'm wrapping the message in a unique way but I don't think that's the best solution,

This is the code:

```
contentscript
window.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
console.log(
  e.target == appIframeContainer
  );
  if (e.data.toString().includes("test")) {
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (data) {
      if (data.test) {
        if (data.test.message == "toggleApp") {
          toggleApp();
        }
      }
    }
   }
}

Inside iframe:

      parent.window.postMessage(
        JSON.stringify({
          test: {
            message: "toggleApp",
            
          },
        }),
        "*",
        []
      );
```

I want to check if it is the iframe that the content script injected not the domain as the domain doesn't matter because content script and the iframe are on same page

Comment: Your MessageEvent has `.source` property you should be able to respond to.

Comment: Yes I can post message on that but how can I check from which iframe it came from

Comment: And to whoever marked my question has answer to, It is not the answer I'm looking for as I don't want to check the domains as the content script and the iframe are on the same page and the domain is from current page, I want to check if it is the iframe that the content script injected.

Comment: The MessageEvent.source will point to the iframe that did post the message. So you just have to check if that's your iframe. But better just post to your original source without going through the parent.

Comment: And the linked answer is not about finding the iframe's origin, it's about finding which iframe did post a message, even when they can't access that iframe content, which is just what you asked for.